# Bootstrap - Change card style with container width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I want to show different views of cards for medium and smaller devices. I need to change the card style according to the width of the container.
For large devices I have this card style:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">Project One</a>
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur eum quasi sapiente nesciunt? Voluptatibus sit, repellat sequi itaque deserunt, dolores in, nesciunt, illum tempora ex quae? Nihil, dolorem!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And for medium and small devices I need this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0" src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h3>Project One</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">View Project</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have no idea how to do this. Can someone suggest the best/most optimized way for accomplishing this?

Comment: Use `hidden-sm` `hidden-xs`.. etc.  Read more here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: Or, since the OP is using Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap Display Property to hide the div in specific screen size.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/